# playing a sound using html5/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

**My Problem:** I would like a user to hear a sound of some sort if a number is over 100.

```
If (x > 100) { play sound }
```

How would I go about this using html5/javascript. Is it possible to play sound without having an inline little video clip. The only stuff I've seen thus far has those little quicktime players embedded within the page: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp

Hopefully there's a better solution? Thanks

Comment: Please checkout http://musquitojs.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [an `<audio>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-audio-element.html#the-audio-element).

```
var foo = document.createElement('audio');
foo.src = 'https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8090976/Matrix%20Ring.aiff';

if (x > 100)
{
    document.getElementById('foo').play();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/ZcRt9/

More reading: http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser

Comment: so this will not create any inline clip, but will actually just allow me to play an audio snippet?

Comment: Edited to use `document.createElement()` instead of an existing one in the page. N.B. you do not need to create a new element every time you want to play a sound; you can re-use the same one.

Comment: great! so if I have the sound clip hosted on my server somewhere, I can just link to it using the whole URL??

Comment: jsfiddle doesnt seem to be working for me. It is not producing any sound on either Chrome or Firefox

Comment: My demo works for me in Safari on a Mac. It's possible that the codec isn't compatible with your OS/browser combination; try an mp3.

Comment: Ok, I've gotten this to work in my web application using the method above, however it is showing the inline clip that I wanted to avoid. Anything you can think of two eliminate that or hide it? Thanks again

Comment: <audio id="foo" hidden="true" src="alarmsound.wav" controls preload="auto" autobuffer></audio> Solved.